# Call method in sequence with parameters cocos2d-x v3.1

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I just want to call a method in a sequence that will accept a Sprite type argument -

My code so far -

```
auto obstacleSprite   =   CCSprite::create(OBSTACLE_SPRITE);
obstacleSprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width*0.25,visibleSize.height*0.15));
this->addChild(obstacleSprite);

Sequence *seq   =   Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(randomDelay),CallFunc::create( std::bind(&GamePlayScene::createObstacles,this) ), NULL);

this->runAction(seq);
```

Method to be called

```
void GamePlayScene::createObstacles(Sprite *spriteObj){
    CCLOG("HA HA HA");
}
```

I am not getting how to pass the Sprite(obstacleSprite) object in CallFunc. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this (I can't test it right now):

```
Sequence *seq = Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(randomDelay), CallFunc::create(std::bind(&GamePlayScene::createObstacles, this, obstacleSprite)), NULL);
```

Also, take a look on: "tests/cpp-tests/Classes/ActionsTest/ActionsTest.cpp", lines 981 and 1010.